# Cookie path and expiry is not working or set after authentication cookie in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Source code  :

```
Response.Cookies.Append("Id", "123456",, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions() 
{ 
    Path = "/user", 
    Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) 
})
```

Can anyone find what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At start remove doubled comma in `Response.Cookies.Append` and will work (but you need to be on `/user` path to see that cookie)